# cacerts - incompatibility Open JDK/JRE vs. Oracle JDK/JRE?

Tags: java, java-8

Is there a known difference or incompatibility of some sort between
**cacerts** file (or **cacerts** file format) when used under Oracle JDK/JRE 8 vs. Open JDK/JRE 8?

I mean... it seems we have a **cacerts** file which works OK with:

(1) Oracle JRE 8 (CentOS release 6.8)
but does not work OK with
(2) Open JRE 8 (CentOS release 6.10).

The Java version on system (1) is

```
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

while on system (2) it is

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)
```

The error we get is this one:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error:`
`java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException:`
`the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty`

Is that possible to be due to the JRE being different or am I completely off base and the issue is elsewhere?

I am not finding any good explanation on the web.

Comment: could you post code

Comment: This question could use more details, what is exact version of oracle/openjdk? How do you launch application using either of them?

Comment: @PirosaysReinstateMonica I added some more information.

Answer (score 2):

`cacerts` sees updates in minor version updates of java. There is no difference between oracleJRE8 and OpenJRE8. As a sidenote, JRE as a concept is obsolete, please transition away from them (if you(r company) wrote the software and are running it yourself, run it on a full JDK. If someone else did, advise them they are using an obsolete stack; they should be giving you the runtime instead of asking you to download and install one and keep it up to date).

A bunch of other stuff has been changed, such as the default format (instead of JKS, it's PKCS12), but that only affects what happens when you *make* new keystores without explicitly specifying which format it should be in (java could, and can, read either format, for all versions of java8) - so that doesn't sound relevant.

It boils down to: No, there is no difference. Whatever problem you have is most likely either related to your platform (for example, ubuntu has a bug where it borks up your cacerts. Long fixed, but maybe you're on that exact version, or you were when you ran apt and ended up with a broken cacerts). That or a million other reasons - no way to tell without more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah, I don't have too much information too as of now. I will research some more myself too, and will post more info here. But you're saying there's no incompatibility generally... which is good.

Comment: It's CentOS `CentOS release 6.10 (Final)` Could that be having the same issue as Ubuntu? Could you point me (a few links) to that known Ubuntu problem?

Comment: Instructions on how to force ubuntu to re-apply: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004745/java-cant-find-cacerts which probably isn't relevant to centos. Bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ca-certificates-java/+bug/1396760

Comment: OK, thank you, I will take a further look. The good news is that (as you say) there shouldn't be any incompatibilities in general.